# Free space on SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since the Express edition is limited to 10 GB (couldn't figure out if it was 'per database' or as a whole since the documentation is confusing,well at least for me), I am wondering is there a way to check this space availability i.e how much have I used so far ? I used some suggestions from the internet but somehow not all of my databases show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right ... Did some googling and found a much better solution:

```
SELECT name AS 'File Name' , physical_name AS 'Physical Name', size/128 AS 'Total Size in MB',

size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 AS 'Available Space In MB', *

FROM sys.database_files;
```

even better :

```
SELECT DB_NAME(A.DATABASE_ID) AS DBNAME,A.NAME AS FILENAME ,

SIZE/128.0 AS CURRENTSIZE_MB,

B.RECOVERY_MODEL_DESC,A.TYPE_DESC ,

CASE WHEN IS_PERCENT_GROWTH = 0

THEN LTRIM(STR(A.GROWTH * 8.0 / 1024,10,1)) + ' MB, '

ELSE 'BY ' + CAST(A.GROWTH AS VARCHAR) + ' PERCENT, 'END +

CASE WHEN MAX_SIZE = -1 THEN 'UNRESTRICTED GROWTH'

ELSE 'RESTRICTED GROWTH TO ' +LTRIM(STR(MAX_SIZE * 8.0 / 1024,10,1)) + ' MB'

END AS AUTOGROW,A.PHYSICAL_NAME

FROM SYS.MASTER_FILES A JOIN SYS.DATABASES B

ON A.DATABASE_ID =B.DATABASE_ID

--WHERE A.PHYSICAL_NAME LIKE 'E%'

-- AND A.FILE_ID =2

ORDER BY A.SIZE/128.0 DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

The 10 GB is for data file size. You can get percentage used of each file like this:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT name, [file] = physical_name, size = size * 8, 
    su_bytes = FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') * 8
  FROM sys.database_files
)
SELECT name, [file], size, SpaceUsed = su_bytes,
  [SpaceUsed%] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), su_bytes*100.0/size)
FROM x;
```

As follows from the [manual on `sys.database_files`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx), the `size` column holds the size expressed in 8K pages, hence multiplying the value by 8 gives you the size in kilobytes. Same applies to the result of [`FILEPROPERTY(..., 'SpaceUsed')`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188401.aspx). To obtain the amounts in other units, change the calculations accordingly.

Comment: Does not show me space used in MB just numbers. Space used : 472 does not tell me much

Comment: @user763539 You just multiply by 8 to get KB. Divide if you want it expressed in MB.

Comment: @user763539: You don't really need much effort to start learning things on your own: looking up `sys.database_files` or `FILEPROPERTY` to learn what the size returned by those expresses is trivial. In all fairness, however, I'll admit that you need no effort *at all* to continue being spoon-fed. The choice is yours.

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for the edit. Not the kind of spoon-feeding I typically do by default. :-)